# Display user-defined types and their details

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-type, catalogs

I've created a few new UDTs in PostgreSQL. However, now I have two problems:

1. how to see which UDTs have been defined?
2. how to see the columns defined within these UDTs?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything on that in the PostgreSQL documentation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Does this get you started?

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema,
        pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) AS name,
        t.typname AS internal_name,
        CASE
            WHEN t.typrelid != 0
            THEN CAST ( 'tuple' AS pg_catalog.text )
            WHEN t.typlen < 0
            THEN CAST ( 'var' AS pg_catalog.text )
            ELSE CAST ( t.typlen AS pg_catalog.text )
        END AS size,
        pg_catalog.array_to_string (
            ARRAY( SELECT e.enumlabel
                    FROM pg_catalog.pg_enum e
                    WHERE e.enumtypid = t.oid
                    ORDER BY e.oid ), E'\n'
            ) AS elements,
        pg_catalog.obj_description ( t.oid, 'pg_type' ) AS description
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
    LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
        ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
    WHERE ( t.typrelid = 0
            OR ( SELECT c.relkind = 'c'
                    FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
                    WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid
                )
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el
                WHERE el.oid = t.typelem
                    AND el.typarray = t.oid
            )
        AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
        AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
        AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible ( t.oid )
    ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

In psql you can `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on` to make psql show you the queries 
used to generate the output of the `\d...` commands. I've found these queries 
to be very useful as a starting point when digging metadata out of databases.

**Update: 2019-12-16**

For composite types, the columns metadata can be determined using something like the following:

```
WITH types AS (
    SELECT n.nspname,
            pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) AS obj_name,
            CASE
                WHEN t.typrelid != 0 THEN CAST ( 'tuple' AS pg_catalog.text )
                WHEN t.typlen < 0 THEN CAST ( 'var' AS pg_catalog.text )
                ELSE CAST ( t.typlen AS pg_catalog.text )
                END AS obj_type,
            coalesce ( pg_catalog.obj_description ( t.oid, 'pg_type' ), '' ) AS description
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
            ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
        WHERE ( t.typrelid = 0
                OR ( SELECT c.relkind = 'c'
                        FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
                        WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid ) )
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                        FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el
                        WHERE el.oid = t.typelem
                        AND el.typarray = t.oid )
            AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
            AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
            AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
),
cols AS (
    SELECT n.nspname::text AS schema_name,
            pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) AS obj_name,
            a.attname::text AS column_name,
            pg_catalog.format_type ( a.atttypid, a.atttypmod ) AS data_type,
            a.attnotnull AS is_required,
            a.attnum AS ordinal_position,
            pg_catalog.col_description ( a.attrelid, a.attnum ) AS description
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t
            ON a.attrelid = t.typrelid
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
            ON ( n.oid = t.typnamespace )
        JOIN types
            ON ( types.nspname = n.nspname
                AND types.obj_name = pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) )
        WHERE a.attnum > 0
            AND NOT a.attisdropped
)
SELECT cols.schema_name,
        cols.obj_name,
        cols.column_name,
        cols.data_type,
        cols.ordinal_position,
        cols.is_required,
        coalesce ( cols.description, '' ) AS description
    FROM cols
    ORDER BY cols.schema_name,
            cols.obj_name,
            cols.ordinal_position ;
```

Comment: I'd upvote *twice* if I could for you bonus info of **`\set ECHO_HIDDEN on`**.  (I mention this here as a comment specifically because it can be easily overlooked in skimming through your answer)

Answer (score 30):

The default clients have functionality to cover that:

#### [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org/)

Default GUI.

[image: types in pgAdmin4]

Make sure types are enabled in the object browser: *File - Preferences - Browser - Nodes*.

To the left you see user-defined types in the chosen schema. (Question **1**)

The `SQL pane` to the right has the reverse engineered SQL script for the selected type. (Question **2**)

More details in the other panes, like `Dependents` etc.

#### [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

The standard interactive console.

1. `\dT` to get a list of user-defined types.
2. `\d type_name` to get the column definition list for the given *composite* type. (Does nothing for other types.)

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

> `\d[S+] [ pattern ]`
>
> For each relation (table, view, materialized view, index, sequence, or foreign table) **or composite type** matching the *pattern*, show all columns, their types, [...]

Bold emphasis mine. The command works for composite types as well since at least Postgres 9.1.

And:

> `\dT[S+] [ pattern ]`
>
> Lists data types. If pattern is specified, only types whose names match the pattern are listed. If `+` is appended to the command name,
> each type is listed with its internal name and size, its allowed
> values if it is an `enum` type, and its associated permissions. By
> default, only user-created objects are shown; supply a pattern or the
> `S` modifier to include system objects.

Comment: JetBrains IDEs have a database plugin (also packaged as a stand-alone product called DataGrip) that displays user defined types in a similar fashion what is shown here with PGAdmin.

Comment: \d <type_name> does not get you the description of the type, it gets you "Did not find any relation named <type_name>"

Comment: @philosodad: `\d typename` is only useful for composite types (which this question is mainly about). I clarified some more above. (Though I had stressed that fact with bold emphasis before.)

Answer (score 12):

Try execute this code:

```
SELECT
    pg_type.typname, 
     pg_enum.enumlabel
FROM
    pg_type 
JOIN
    pg_enum ON pg_enum.enumtypid = pg_type.oid;
```

Comment: I got no results from this query. Not sure what the data was supposed to look like.

Comment: This query will only return user-defined **enums**. There are other user-defined types (such as composite types) that will not be returned by this query.

Answer (score 4):

*This is a very simple alternative*, but enough for simple use cases. When the column's type is UDT, we use the `udt_name` column from `information_schema.columns` table.

```sql
select column_name, case 
        when (data_type = 'USER-DEFINED') then udt_name 
        else data_type 
    end as data_type
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'altimetria' and table_name = 'cnivel';
```

Result (`geometry`is a UDT):

```
 column_name  |    data_type     
--------------+------------------
 ogc_fid      | integer
 wkb_geometry | geometry
 id_cnivel    | bigint
 cod_cart     | bigint
 cod_fam      | bigint
 cod_sub      | integer
 z            | double precision
 shape_len    | double precision
```

Answer (score 4):

With `psql`:

- `\dT` show list of user-defined types.
- `\dT+ <type_name>` show given user-defined type, with details.
- `\dT <type_name>` show given user-defined type, without details.
- `\d <type_name>` show the column definition of the given user-defined type
  *NOTE: this is a **plain*** `\d`, *and describes the type in a similar fashion to a table*

Comment: This adds nothing to existing answers, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only answer that includes the `\dT+` command which is exactly what I needed

Comment: This answer does add something. No other answer contains \dT+ <type_name>, which actually gets you the description of the type.

Comment: The one thing missing from this answer was the plain `\d` that gives the column definition of a UDT - that solves the OP's problem #2.  I've added it to the answer.  *And*, that's the one I *always* forget!  And I like this answer, because it's short & sweet for `psql`

Answer (score -1):

Using [the anwser of gsiems](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35510/212793), I've archived the goal to mimic the 'CREATE TYPE' in PgAdmin & PgBackup

```
WITH types AS (
    SELECT n.nspname,
            pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) AS obj_name,
            CASE
                WHEN t.typrelid != 0 THEN CAST ( 'tuple' AS pg_catalog.text )
                WHEN t.typlen < 0 THEN CAST ( 'var' AS pg_catalog.text )
                ELSE CAST ( t.typlen AS pg_catalog.text )
                END AS obj_type,
            coalesce ( pg_catalog.obj_description ( t.oid, 'pg_type' ), '' ) AS description
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
            ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
        WHERE ( t.typrelid = 0
                OR ( SELECT c.relkind = 'c'
                        FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
                        WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid ) )
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                        FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el
                        WHERE el.oid = t.typelem
                        AND el.typarray = t.oid )
            AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
            AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
            AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
),
cols AS (
    SELECT n.nspname::text AS schema_name,
            pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) AS obj_name,
            a.attname::text AS column_name,
            pg_catalog.format_type ( a.atttypid, a.atttypmod ) AS data_type,
            a.attnotnull AS is_required,
            a.attnum AS ordinal_position,
            pg_catalog.col_description ( a.attrelid, a.attnum ) AS description
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t
            ON a.attrelid = t.typrelid
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
            ON ( n.oid = t.typnamespace )
        JOIN types
            ON ( types.nspname = n.nspname
                AND types.obj_name = pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) )
        WHERE a.attnum > 0
            AND NOT a.attisdropped
)
SELECT 'CREATE TYPE ' || cols.schema_name || '.' || cols.obj_name || E' AS (\n    ' ||
    pg_catalog.array_to_string (ARRAY( 
        SELECT cols.column_name || ' ' || cols.data_type AS col_num_typ
        FROM cols
        WHERE cols.obj_name='my_user_datatype'
        ORDER BY cols.schema_name,
                cols.obj_name,
                cols.ordinal_position ), E',\n    '
        ) || E'\n);'
    AS cre_typ
FROM cols
WHERE cols.obj_name='my_user_datatype'
LIMIT 1
```

and run it under psql with this commands to have only the SQL code `\t\a\g\a\t`.

Ok in PG 9.6. Say me if it's running with yours instances. Obviously, it need to be optimised and tested.

Answer (score -3):

- Way 1:

```
SELECT typname, typcategory
FROM pg_type
WHERE typname='custom_type_name';
```

- Way 2:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, udt_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name ='your_table_name';
```

Comment: Welcome to [dba stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) Somehow I am not convinced that your answer brings any value to this question. Have you seen the other answers?